# Determine whether a function can be extended

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Given that
$x^2+y^2 < 1$

I have 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,0)} \frac{y}{ \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$$
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,0)} \frac{y^m}{ \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$$
where $m > 1$.

I'm supposed to prove that the first function does not have a limit at $(1, 0)$
whereas the second one can be extended to be continuous at $(1, 0)$

Help please?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: For the first one, try approaching $(1,0)$ first along the $x$ axis, and then along the curve $y = \sqrt {1-x^2}/2.$ The second one looks false to me: Here we can look at a curve of the form $y = \sqrt {1-x^2} -f(x),$ where $f(x)$ is positive but $\to 0$ very fast as $x\to 1^-.$ I'm thinking $f(x) = (1-x^2)^{2m}$ should be small enough to make $y^m/(\sqrt { 1 - x^2 -y^2}$ blow up along this curve.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta)$ where $r^2<1$

then $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,0)} \frac{y}{ \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}=\lim_{(r,\theta)\rightarrow(1,0)} \frac{r\sin(\theta)}{ \sqrt{1-r^2}}=\lim_{(r,\theta)\rightarrow(1,0)} \frac{r\theta}{ \sqrt{1-r^2}}$

Since $r^2<1$ we can let $r=\cos(\alpha)$ then

$\lim_{(r,\theta)\rightarrow(1,0)} \frac{r\theta}{ \sqrt{1-r^2}}=\lim_{(\alpha,\theta)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{\cos(\alpha)\theta}{ \sin(\alpha)}=\lim_{(\alpha,\theta)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{\theta}{\alpha}$

We can easily let  the slope of $\theta\over\alpha$ be anything and hence the limit does not exist.

When $m>1$ however, the limit becomes $\lim_{(\alpha,\theta)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{\theta^m}{\alpha}$ which approaches $0$ from all directions.

Comment: What about the path $\alpha=\theta^m$? Then $\theta^m/\alpha = 1$ for every $\theta\ne 0$, and therefore the limit along this path is $1$ for $\theta\to 0$.

Comment: You cannot have "curved paths" as long as I understand for this type of problem. You have to let $\theta\over\alpha$ be any constant so it approaches $(0,0)$ from a uniform direction.

Comment: Of course we can have curved paths. We are approaching $(1,0)$ from within the unit circle along any path we want.

Comment: I have not come over any problem where non-linear path is allowed and I can't find any reference in a short time. But if that is the case then the problem itself is wrong as $\alpha=\theta^m$ will generate a different limit...

Comment: why does $sin \theta$ goes to $\theta$?

Comment: If you are talking about the last equality in the second line, $sin\theta$ goes to $\theta$ because of the identity ${sin\theta\over\theta}$ goes to $1$.

Comment: but shouldn't it be 0 since $sin$ is continuous

Comment: It depends on what level of tightness you want, $\lim_0(sin\theta)=\lim_0(\theta)$ is definitely a tighter bound than $\lim_0(sin\theta)=0$